# Error when scaling math using "unicode-math" package

Tags: unicode-math

Scaling fails when using the `unicode-math` package the prime (`'`) appears too high.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}    
$y'$\Large$y'$    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a bug report: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues